# Pager element not showing on form

Tags: 8, forms

I have a simple tableselect element inside my form and the tableselect rows are populated using a pager as follows:

```
$pagerLimit = 10; //default value if nothing is passed in
$query = $this->jobSkillStorage->getQuery();
$query->condition('type', $skillType);   
$query->pager($pagerLimit)
$ids = $query->execute();
$jobSkills = $this->jobSkillStorage->loadMultiple($ids);  

return $jobSkills;
```

The pagination limit functions well and only 10 results are returned, however the pagination controls do not show after the tableselect. Please see the full code of how the tableselect was generated.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['vtabs'] = [
    '#type' => 'vertical_tabs',
  ];

  $form['tech_skills' = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => $this->t('Tech Skills'),
    '#group' => 'vtabs',
    'tech_skills_table' => [
      '#type' => 'tableselect',
      '#empty' => $this->t('Your search for tech skills did not return '
          . 'any results.'),  
      '#header' => [
        'name' => $this->t('SKILL NAME'),
        'description' => $this->t('DESCRIPTION'),
        'status' => $this->t('STATUS'),
        'changed' => $this->t('LAST UPDATED'),
        'actions' => $this->t('ACTIONS')  
      ],
      '#options' => $this->getTableOptions(),          
    ],
    'tech_skills_pager' => [
      '#theme' => 'pager',     
    ],         
  ];

  return $form;
```

Most examples of paging I see use $build['pager'] rather than $form['pager']. I'm just wondering if pager isn't a form renderable element? Could that be the reason its not showing? Kinda lost on this. Any thoughts please?

Thanks

Comment: The code above has syntax issues.

Comment: Pls At what point exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `#theme` rather than `#type`. `#type` is for form elements, `#theme` is for themeable elements, that are outside (and also sometimes inside) forms.

As another example, `table` is a `#theme`, whereas `tableselect`, which is a table with form elements, is a `#type`.

Comment: Hey Jaypan, that's a good one. Thanks for speedy answer. I've just changed ```'type' => 'pager'``` to ```'theme' => 'pager' ``` and the pager still doesn't show and I need a tableselect because I need selectable rows. Isn't there a way to use pager with tableselect element?

Comment: Did you use the hashtag? `#theme` not `theme`

Comment: Yes I did ```'#theme' => 'pager'```. I'm going to update the question with my current code shortly. Really pissed off I can't get something so simple to work!

Comment: Maybe move the pager into a render array outside the form.

Comment: I'm still struggling to get this to work, folks. This should be stuff that works out of the box, what am I doing wrong? Pls has anybody else been able to use a pager with a tableselect?

Comment: Did you try moving the pager render array out of the form?